# About mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

usrfrnd_table

```
user_id friend_id
__________________
1         1

2         5

3          1

2          1
```

and usr_table

```
id fullname
________________

1  John Doe

2 George Cann
...
```

How to echo all friends of for example id 2 from table usr_table with loop?
Tried this piece of code. but doesn't work

```
$stmt = "SELECT fullname FROM usr_table INNER JOIN usrfrnd_table ON usr_table.id=usrfrnd_table.friend_id WHERE usrfrnd_table.user_id='$id'";
    $result=$db->query($stmt);
    foreach($result as $rec){
        echo "<li><a href=user.php?id=".$rec['id']."'>". $rec['fullname'] . "</a></li>";
    }
```

Comment: Is the userfrnd_table uni- or bi-directional? And why is user 1 friend of himself? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$stmt = "SELECT id, fullname FROM usr_table INNER JOIN usrfrnd_table ON usr_table.id=usrfrnd_table.friend_id WHERE usrfrnd_table.user_id=2";
$result=mysql_query($stmt);
foreach($result as $rec){
    echo $rec['fullname'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: that join looks like it would return the username of the user being looked at (id=2) instead of the name of his friends

Comment: Right you are...had the wrong join there.  Nice catch, thanks.

Comment: i need fullnames of his friends

Comment: $stmt = "SELECT fullname FROM usr_table INNER JOIN usrfrnd_table ON usr_table.id=usrfrnd_table.friend_id WHERE usrfrnd_table.user_id='$id'";
$result=$db->query($stmt);
foreach($result as $rec){
    echo "<li><a href=user.php?id=".$rec['id']."'>". $rec['fullname'] . "</a></li>";
}  it doesn't work for me. please re check code. $id variable of user id

Comment: If you need the id of the friend, it just needs to be added to the column list in the SELECT statement.  I've updated my answer to give this.

Answer (score 1):

the query would look something like this:

```
select fullname from usr_table inner join usrfrnd_table ON (usr_table.id = usrfrnd_table.friend_id) WHERE usrfrnd_table.user_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are wanting to show all friends of user 2.  You need to do an inner join.

`SELECT usr_table.fullname FROM usrfrnd_table, usr_table WHERE (usrfrnd_table.friend_id = usr_table.id) AND (usrfrnd_table.user_id = 2)`

Comment: This statement would return all friends of all users, you'd have to add the clause that selects friends of user 2 only.

Comment: then how to echo them one by one? mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: see AJ's example, this should now do what you want

Comment: That's right.  It needs an 'AND (usrfrnd_table.user_id = 2)' at the end.  Sorry about that.